# Should I assume an API always returns what its documentation says it will?

Tags: api, exception, language-agnostic

There is an API which according to its documentation will always return:

```
{
  "some": {
    "nested": { "value": 14 }
  }
}
```

I am using version 1 of the API so this shouldn't change.

I have exception handling in place in case the API returns anything other than a 200 status code.

My question is, should I write my code in a way such that it fails gracefully in case the API returns something else? (e.g. 14 is not numeric, "nested" does not exist etc.)

For example:

```
begin
  value = response["some"]["nested"]["value"]
rescue KeyError
  # Do something so that the process can continue
end
```

Would there be any value in this or would it be best to just assume the API will always do what it says, and if it doesn't then the app will throws errors which I will be notified of through our monitoring system?

Usually, I would say you should expect any input from a user, and handle it gracefully. In a sense an API is nothing but a user with a very specific response, on the other hand, if I consider an API to be like an included library then I would assume it responds as intended (e.g. I would never plan for my code to handle `CoolLibrary.add(5, 2)` returning a string)

Note: I have obviously already tested the endpoint and my code is working under normal circumstances

Comment: Well… *do* you have a contingency plan for when the API doesn't return what it's supposed to? If you depend on that information, then presumably the rest of the code can't really continue to work if the API doesn't adhere to the promised specification, in which case aborting everything and erroring out is a cromulent strategy.

Comment: Let's assume for the sake of this question, this gathers some extra information which in case I don't have I can just put in its place a default value or tell the user we couldn't calculate that field. But at the same time I've had this question come up before so it would be good to have an answer for both cases, where this is a critical part of the application. By ensuring it's numeric early on and not a string I could prevent unintended behaviour other than just a crash. (e.g. in Ruby "string".size returns 6 whilst 12.size returns 8, this could lead to many bugs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the possible failure scenarios, regardless of how *likely* it is that they will occur. Of course the API *should* always return what it promises, but errors are exactly that and will happen when you least expect them. It's an external system, not under your control, and prone to all sorts of errors from network problems to dumb typos by the 3rd party. So, assume that the API *will* fail to return the expected data *someday*, and consider what would happen then.

- Would your code naturally produce an error/exception, or would it cause silent creeping data corruption?

  If the former and an API failure already produces a code failure, you're good on that front. If the latter, you'll want to add explicit sanity checks to produce explicit errors.

  Something sane here is to cast the API data to a data structure defined in your code, in the process of which some type checking or schema validation will occur. This gives you type safety throughout your code.
- Can you continue on without that API data, or is it critical to the entire following chain of events?

  If it's "optional" data, handle the error case accordingly and continue with some default data or alternative strategy. If it's required data, let the errors bubble up to be handled by an appropriate higher-level caller, because obviously you can't continue without it.

Comment: Couldn't you say the same about the `CoolLibrary` example I gave? Sure I have access to the source code and updates happen when I say they should, but I'm never really going to look at the source code. Yet, I'm guessing you wouldn't recommend I check the `add()` function doesn't return a string if the docs say it will return a number. Even if that would cause data corruption. Why are these 2 situations different? (sorry, I'm mostly playing devils advocate so that I can understand better why these are different, I'm not arguing against your points)

Comment: You have a lot more control over code that you're executing locally, depending on your language you even have type checking and compilation steps which would rule out such misbehaviour entirely before runtime. Web APIs however will _only_ surface errors at runtime and hence need runtime checks, if you're so inclined as to do the checking.